# Focus LCDs FTSN LCD Application

Tags: pcb, lcd

I am creating a pcb that uses part number G126CLGFGLW6WTCCXAL from Focus LCDs, which is an FTSN display along with the ST7565R driver. [The datasheet](https://focuslcds.com/content/G126CLGFGLW6WTCCXAL_Spec.pdf) isn't clear as to how v0-v4 should be connected to the internal charge pump circuit. What is the correct way for me to wire this?

Answer (score 1):

You connect 9v (Maximum voltage is up to 13.5v but typical is 9v) to pins V0-V4 and the ground to the other ground (pin 15). Double check everything I said so it makes sense to you. I did not read the entire datasheet so I could have missed something.
[image: LCD_V0-V4]

Comment: What confuses me is the datasheet for the specific driver chip (not the whole lcd module) shows application circuits which are the following:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/656770973852237844/1092836340346920990/image.png?width=915&height=611

Comment: I would not bother with the driver chip data sheet unless the module manufacturer specifically tell you to do so for specific reasons.